# Is it possible to get an instagram names from facebook api?

Tags: facebook, instagram, social-media

Is it possible to get an Instagram account name for each of your Facebook friends via Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible.

- You can´t get a list of all your Facebook friends anymore, only a list of those who authorized your App too.
- Facebook bought Instagram, but that does not matter those two platforms are combined. There´s no field for the Instagram account in the User table.